# Do we know if there are asteroids leading or following Earth in Earth's orbit around the Sun?

Tags: the-sun, orbit, earth, asteroids

A search of the Internet is so clouded with discussions about the asteroid belt or asteroids *orbiting the planet Earth* that I couldn't see an answer to my question.

Do we know if there are asteroids orbiting the Sun *in Earth's orbit* (NOT *orbiting the Earth).*

To be clear: these would be asteroids located somewhere around the Sun at the same distance as Earth, either following it or leading it in the Earth's own orbit around the Sun.

*I hope that was clear.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several known [Earth co-orbital asteroids](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2002Icar..160....1M/abstract). The [first to be discovered](https://doi.org/10.1038%2F42662) was [(3753) Cruithne](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=3753), which is often mistakenly described as "Earth's second moon". Cruithne has a bean-shaped orbit when viewed in a reference frame rotating with the Earth.

The only known [Earth Trojan](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2011Natur.475..481C/abstract) is [2010 TK<sub>7</sub>](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=3548081), which orbits the L<sub>4</sub> point located 60° ahead of the Earth.

Comment: That's what I was missing... the correct search term!

Comment: @JBH for a larger list of close, but not quite the same orbit, google Earth crossing or Earth grazing.    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Earth-crossing_minor_planets and for an even larger subset, Near Earth Objects.